# What's the most common aspect ratio in terms of web design?

Tags: website-design, aspect-ratio

I'd like to know what is the most common aspect ratio to aim for in web design? I'm having problems with a site that works fine in 1920x1080 (16:9), but it doesn't work out so great in 1680x1050 (16:10). I just want to decide which would be the best choice to aim for. I realise there are mobile resolutions to bear in mind, but I'm thinking specifically of desktop users.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Common screen resolution?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/6929/common-screen-resolution)

Comment: @locationunknown it is related and the answer for my question could be derived from the answer to that one... but my question was specifically about aspect ratio. The answer provided by Tohster is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a question that can be answered easily and quickly by Google.

But since it is a popular question, here's a reusable approach:

- W3Schools keeps [statistics on web browser screen widths](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_display.asp).
- The last set is from Jan 2014, but it's enough to make the point since the movement has been towards 16:9 since then:

---

[image: vriwser stats]

---

Based on this analysis I would certainly aim for 16:9 for desktops.  Remember that browsers usually have even higher aspect ratios because the nav/tab bar and status bar will reduce the height more than the scrollbar reduces width.

But the popularity of 16:9 isn't an excuse for poor design.  **It's usually important to ensure websites render well on a range of window sizes**, because users don't always browse with the browser window maximized.  Even if they do, desktop users often have taskbars (e.g. windows, mac) or sidebars (e.g. chat, social) which will change the browser aspect ratio.

Comment: Thanks very much! I will always keep in mind different aspect ratios of course!

Comment: Happy it helped... Good luck and welcome to the site :-)

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is, your web design should not be dependent on the aspect ratio of the user's device. Using proper modern day techniques, a.k.a Responsive design, means that your website/webapp should be readily fluid between a phone's portrait view to a 16:9, 4K desktop screen.

Comment: One example where it is dependent on the user's device is that the background image has some content that should be visible. The background image itself can be dynamic and exist on every screen size, but different parts of the background image are getting cropped away. Designing background images with content that should be visible, can be good to know the aspect ratio to have the parts wanted to be shown to be visible.