# What's the reference screen resolutions to start preparing mockups for desktop?

Tags: desktop-application, screen-resolution

I need to justify my choice of screen resolutions for a PWA desktop app that runs to run on old and newest PCs. So far mockups are preapred for 1440? I don't have specific information which lead to simple decision of downscaling or upscaling. Maybe there is some market standard which i don't know about or some good practices in this topic. Thanks in advance. This is my first topic ever.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Common screen resolution?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/6929/common-screen-resolution)

Answer (score 4):

Design for the most common screen resolution in your userbase. If it's an internal company application then you can hopefully find out the various devices being used boy contacting the internal IT department. If it's an external application then you'll have to go by statistics available in that location.

Sites like https://gs.statcounter.com/screen-resolution-stats can give you stats by country, which is a place to start.

HOWEVER - just because screens have a certain resolution, that doesn't mean the application window will always be set to maximum for all users to make the most of. People use applications in all sorts of ways, have different sized monitors connected, have them set to different zoom levels... So you need to make sure the application can scale to a variety of different sizes.